# How to detect if a color is in RGB, HSL or HEX format?

Tags: javascript, colors

I have the following which detects if a color is HEX, RGB or HSL:

```
function detectColorFormat(color) {
  if (color.startsWith('#')) {
    return 'HEX';
  } else if (color.startsWith('rgb')) {
    return 'RGB';
  } else if (color.startsWith('hsl')) {
    return 'HSL';
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality without having to be so specific with the color string input?

For example, how can we make it so:

```
"ff0" //returns HEX
"#ff0" //returns HEX
"fffF00" // returns HEX

"250 50 10" //returns RGB
"250, 50, 10" //returns RGB
"rgb(250,50,10)" //returns RGB

"10,50%,80%" //returns HSL
```

Even better if this includes RGBA format also

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73158976/how-do-i-use-a-javascript-library-locally-without-a-server has a better solution than the one suggested in the comments. Would you like to undelete it so I can post the solution?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks! I undeleted it but I think there was a misunderstanding. I'm not trying to run a Node server locally, the library I linked is a Javascript library that even has a CDN, but the creator won't give instructions for how to run it locally. He just assumes every single programmer on the planet is using Node

Answer (score 1):

Not yet.
In the future you will be probably able to use [CSS Typed Object Model API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Typed_OM_API) but it's not widely used and completely implemented even in the browsers that started to implement it.

Currently, you will have to use something similar to your approach (maybe you could have a regexp), but keep in mind you could have also named color (such as "red", for example) that are totally valid color value in CSS.