# How do I use a Javascript library locally without a server?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the following [library](https://github.com/meodai/color-names#cdn-), which extracts names from colors:

The problem is that they have a Javascript CDN, but they don't tell you how to use it unless you're using Node.

```
import namedColors from 'color-name-list';

let someColor = namedColors.find(color => color.hex === '#ffffff');
console.log(someColor.name); // => white

let someNamedColor = namedColors.find(color => color.name === 'Eigengrau')
console.log(someColor.hex); // => #16161d
```

I don't use node or a server so import doesn't work, how do I run this locally?

Comment: you have to install node and server package locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place it's hosted is on unpkg, which doesn't have cross-origin restrictions, so you may `fetch` from the endpoint listed in the docs:

```js
fetch('https://unpkg.com/color-name-list@9.18.1/dist/colornames.json')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result[0].name);
    // put code here that depends on the library
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```

The library also has its own API, which can be used:

```js
fetch('https://api.color.pizza/v1/')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.colors[0].name);
    // put code here that depends on the library
  })
  // .catch(handleErrors);
```